# system.arraycopy is copying the whole array instead of just a chunk?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have some code for an Android app that's supposed to break any message larger than 6kb into chunks, before sending it to a server.

Here is the code that does the "chunking":

```
 //split the post data into 6k chunks
             int chunkSize = 6144, chunks = size / chunkSize;
             int remaining = size - (chunks * chunkSize);
             android.util.Log.v("INFO-----------------------------------","chunks " + chunks+", " + remaining);
             nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(0);
             int offset = 0;
             for(int i=0;i< chunks;i++)
             {
                 byte[] bytes = new byte[chunkSize];
                 System.arraycopy(postData,offset, bytes, 0, chunkSize);
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(REQUEST_PARAMETER_NAME, new String(bytes).trim()));
                 offset += chunkSize;
                 android.util.Log.v("INFO------------"+(i+1)+"------------------","-------------------" + bytes.length);
                 android.util.Log.v("",new String(bytes).trim());
                 android.util.Log.v("INFO-----------------------------------","-------------------");
             }

             if(remaining > 0)
             {
                 byte[] remainingBytes = new byte[remaining];
                 System.arraycopy(postData,offset, remainingBytes, 0, remaining);     
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(REQUEST_PARAMETER_NAME, new String(remainingBytes).trim()));
                     android.util.Log.v("INFO-----------------------------------","-------------------");
                     android.util.Log.v("",new String(remainingBytes).trim());
                     android.util.Log.v("INFO-----------------------------------","-------------------");
                 }
```

Now for some reason, the first array `bytes` always ends up with all of the contents of the original array, instead of just a part of it (`bytes.length = postData.length`).

The weirdest part is that the `remainingBytes` array contains exactly the last remaining parts of the original array.

EDIT (logcat) pretty long

**Original content:**

```
V/        (  766): 
X1MGjey46m/voRnS7eI+nNcZMqBkIbJGGFC2GpIt1ElV69U9t8MUD4jbzFyj1sfxLQJD1p4AUIsYoGejj1jDMVEwpbrXzEbmvuWDIqSulEDS0MCx69srF+wca
pJtFRCfFgU2FIfuAO58+rknTuqlh0D6lB2DA+jSWd0KXTwFS+pX3oWueokg0AyX85VHxzUICbU0FiywkE2l4W77kBpKbZ2QUnIwHZFWkivAOiUy4Gq+qkduwQtrJsIwsOIyMYJJYMnEO
Ayfb0pJrjfe2smQt0tgZNNFSmVlR2euzoE5YlyDQ8Ut0o+UULrC9switwNmUcorBDa4ubWpGkmcImQ++lNLsrK+/B/gtF1uAnpDHRc8nybtp/4Mhdx5pw4iDHkHlDuVEW0GP3QyO1fjC
474RHXMcV99tbxYeC2Go+aPHpksx6wnlp+UqPeQcMqJc1GUVnhx8nTAB45g/fJf7WL0qmwPKxhWm87EzqACoQKIy8L9+tLSV7+CXTGXZ4zA4KBmCEEOEqMfBMk+m1LqU15FhbWTLodbp
04J1mbidOxE2Qc0q6iS6rpILSINxReTxA+tr0tuqNIBPC6f17GGTHwDOBWx5LKzodJTZ361rEOeg/95Mlpzm5wd8WNu+TunFKeLnZR0gQGbc7TpHQBfjRI1jWMP/6TueRxUeUZD3D4Vv
19qO+PRIZjyZknMB407sh/bFVXtZaMnrxoKLnqEF+pIDrU0+otdF9mfN9CgfFaI9Ctbff1JENdDfgJ3Wr2ZZLJoSQFhegmXcHdHS9EC26l6h9DUkMbyzChq60PkCqQGSxbIRFRKkDo2p
Oe/1HzHJ98GNAwwxzxwlRrLnCzKBjkvjCJSDf22lSGThcq9VrDUlw4J1b4vwyjXGFtu+nc1uj20cAnbQJeSGIj4d5gGorefvTeaH7zzIwpOBKnf+f88rb5w7F8/KsvI3KxHXBmtmEK2M
DGuRFkgW9jsULhj+T06t8hfGOnuzZ/RwV7V70u6PIK+kSWU3mdERRUE3YvydEmhQaQUG6C0dut9FSJpC5MYEJTJkjpQriw/fZLoPz2E/2bar8RdU51uyc47JP2b2fTtNQ4XXh8R8qqAp
8022P5jWyUr47rR3xfo2k2PXS+rw8uPd9VtqyY0lCdUCRkIhMoy5gcWyB/rjp+vP1EevsPzGPKZlS6mDzANGg+OJGcBTa59/soZTSxqBrVtQQK9hd0ao2KYrej50QRT0tp/piGG/tXMi
yzDgsYHQ2Eq+Hb1pZJPIHNZjo4UdvIvIDTxgqpsW/bdphE+ONKT/H1Mfy7qqf3E18U2lMuGHmT/YVGsIhco2ltp6YmLgyL9X3fkD+cX3B11EMKJN06tiW4hvEu9AySDL5SQRENmpvo9a
Ha118jjxb99NenFXKGCJxnH5xutiZl/ibYaBzLDsGVxIPBJkpJy14XdP34or7pYsiC45UlHnTzmbUuD4ANn2OIE0wxMPeTedcqiSWW3Upn0kwZezstDukudqyIcwZRJ79btM7h6cOetW
C9uIIgl26oUNmDzLx/tLZVHzRDE211iVSbn4oDFzqNjC1uPz02Bp2HOsmRuwc3tkACs6UP7yXIPxAmexgqbiYp0iy7KoVxUdnnA6HxD5EL/na+zmwdHDFmmRW6Vey8M83KhQaOVIamSi
9AG7tp21YstbVx3/bP0LonxctyISr1lh2EH4qjlLGTnWQccM7u1GNaQJhStpYFzIKbakChNVgoSKTRE0jRn9B/+6LaJfvugYfQILmInU0y243L70WYRd6VAr2OO9pnVdyvULnLm7iK04
ys5gXm3bcpm+9TT/G8pzVr2955ND8cN++pgQIUIeFnhYAw6w02dG7P4A+NSRalPODYdrwEVPFK5gUE6cG+vRn9zLEa2BT+q35B//aT1ICt1RIrXbx9JVssOS0l8T8TCrwjkcKYi9pdqi
St3hv//FJDqZ9QarG77GSOCHYO5ldYdUijIBTFwHkmG1u9gogbjcOytH1Jy9hmXAvb+3/f5X80hkEey9VHzjMJmcsivRLvU1My3vb1Tlrp/eNb8Z/as41yDy4rQT5hqCuQBVjFO5nEAC
PFbSMKe8W/+uoEijTxhApBolYVZzEvDiYM/0zEQC5REJp0ZQaTiWAadEXIsV2oBFPi9S2ZkrTnW5pmmDE7BKDtssxiNdmrGSeQe/bcAPmYmWxFeQrDOTevtyb6EZmvUcxJL5AaJTcA9g
e8RVyV09TFvStd6eUuKEoHO7BYpSnJXF4evnP2qLSozcZPtOnYxE3D1qxnJcx1xSl0j3OHEWc66sWB/U3P3awbPoMKLjAsTJTJnCqWxYntNMsQdvAcWLVgbEOkDdNnYH50PgQsujZcSd
Q8Vx9Kii+bUQyh+1C/FC4ohuhtKYGP2c1DTqQ0A9NVm8nwsWGUrg+sVA+QehwFhEakYiKy5r9rc9pLR5hixWxDTpZqx98gMJohFrJDWJ9VjZeaiciR+fizEyyMCT3NCFMmeGNka8DSMR
gOWu5/0mEdgqN0zU0OVCsGD0a086PlyNq202eQqhDYEiXYyip0m5AdzCl/8V9r9m7xmTKg0kbypw0FIJkQonwex2TZ2oGL2437+Youcw55HYWT/RJt3ubsOUJYuJOzxNRmNyziBCyXEG
eWKVyqAp1V0koF/8QjpkYpLmcJ0eCFgODDEidtt8Zl/GlJAAWQF/v7wX/ZnsDBgvdK7Swyx+USCX6Xm0yumrhDionYPQZAgat+3VjqV2ZVGC7/rtpuvQkaMIn+4tNuEPfudxkZ2LhNwh
9NGxKex4KIykxBbaPOt5WaW7TqiVmGwQMK7dkqIcG9s2gMdGFGPWzaApb3xwyWOwVp++7aC5ROBumH0JC+UybNNUTGxpKvs9c0Q1+7hZDanS6PkIXt2E3420hx5cDjnUQCWA6BgqMmLj
XR/ACRwOp5uD2mmN5Y52C1rKiMOOugUdeRPqUkCy+EA6aP2gG+UxCTxn10dufpAHuo0FrgJkppHuhEaZyLTnnwxqNtiRW0qux1GuXRbqtDKNXWY1ktKrsHJwbC9DhE+zHHqp87aNDT7H
vyDAD1bDRnOYwqo8fMeLLtqkxKlDkCgTdmUkyO/Ex0jTg9OEeAsh5sQMI8xHvKocRPWEM6lVPLlPjuKsDTnWRNx8469nwWfewsz9FvoeHA6gVIfuBk75dNIsjA3gtIOXUKCFruo9GQCH
d9h9BYQplVsgO5kLKWAaI/zeb7/L1MzwhrLChda5Apj6zSLMPTruPXV8Hkyp4EbvsVF5MfENQDDs2FrNR6PeBLWoAHlpfuwf0MKXsVb3oeNU2ujK+h+RNLCVmQZnPzSDYoVDm7/rl7/g
Fdhr/1DajPPqDs2fPW8v0EW8Em7T6K8LcKMGaufPFVr85kWt52imgnYUJNOGUOJMtqrA+IrbnArGJ8oFfC44vtL1S1X0d1awNBR1oZpZ3WPDBpM4EiIDp7FHtgUaLmlnmzjutIwf/sJk
K8aXHZiI9mOYFuAOZsSm3rKjr3hCUdr5E43yhkIGcp6aJgpOip+nPDmseT5QXbiZpd9NuJcobjqA48wtshYf82c14ThPT9Ej5ETyMRwZDjTgrUFcnTCPdWYnKyQPlx/oDOWAszeag6dw
EcgG0LuT6MfFU+qqchdOqJn807KT/Vqummn0oVRZIhn2hKsy2PJECv2l6vz45th5SR9MhR3l/+DtO5j/y1mdX4lNpibBkzfj+3BYp5HaLbYb6v3QeOpqPjadSS8HPsaklKq+qgMBp+9x
T6hlS2tS537lL1peDrD4IIKZmiQOrNbpTdAJ2uIQuIRQo51ruI+8/I1mbC9zTkpAfHE4QUSSyqoN7vNcqIKtIEDfQdjMu5fZG5PJkdoACE3z2a5VPwMV2sNQNnUpLh8bWYlxd5Sq73ea
n8ioKH9Wh2Kssap3+lb5vVtMzXR/1rGSsRFktw0SWRDjwSCkXi6EZoMrmQ9UCnPSUbkhQo3KYwrEJ5QvjazIpFRhrxO9gR9bo2c35iXAkER7Md3xYi8vstTdAQPQjgQEhl/JQbaoXCsV
Xwe6S/mZ3WJFVYh/O/hpdBoe8mlS9bwh
V/INFO-----------------------------------(  766): -------------------
```

**First chunk:**

```
V/INFO------------1------------------(  766): -------------------
V/        (  766): X1MGjey46m/voRnS7eI+nNcZMqBkIbJGGFC2GpIt1ElV69U9t8MUD4jbzFyj1sfxLQJD1p4AUIsYoGejj1jDMVEwpbrXzEbmvuWDIqSulEDS0MCx69srF+wca
pJtFRCfFgU2FIfuAO58+rknTuqlh0D6lB2DA+jSWd0KXTwFS+pX3oWueokg0AyX85VHxzUICbU0FiywkE2l4W77kBpKbZ2QUnIwHZFWkivAOiUy4Gq+qkduwQtrJsIwsOIyMYJJYMnEO
Ayfb0pJrjfe2smQt0tgZNNFSmVlR2euzoE5YlyDQ8Ut0o+UULrC9switwNmUcorBDa4ubWpGkmcImQ++lNLsrK+/B/gtF1uAnpDHRc8nybtp/4Mhdx5pw4iDHkHlDuVEW0GP3QyO1fjC
474RHXMcV99tbxYeC2Go+aPHpksx6wnlp+UqPeQcMqJc1GUVnhx8nTAB45g/fJf7WL0qmwPKxhWm87EzqACoQKIy8L9+tLSV7+CXTGXZ4zA4KBmCEEOEqMfBMk+m1LqU15FhbWTLodbp
04J1mbidOxE2Qc0q6iS6rpILSINxReTxA+tr0tuqNIBPC6f17GGTHwDOBWx5LKzodJTZ361rEOeg/95Mlpzm5wd8WNu+TunFKeLnZR0gQGbc7TpHQBfjRI1jWMP/6TueRxUeUZD3D4Vv
19qO+PRIZjyZknMB407sh/bFVXtZaMnrxoKLnqEF+pIDrU0+otdF9mfN9CgfFaI9Ctbff1JENdDfgJ3Wr2ZZLJoSQFhegmXcHdHS9EC26l6h9DUkMbyzChq60PkCqQGSxbIRFRKkDo2p
Oe/1HzHJ98GNAwwxzxwlRrLnCzKBjkvjCJSDf22lSGThcq9VrDUlw4J1b4vwyjXGFtu+nc1uj20cAnbQJeSGIj4d5gGorefvTeaH7zzIwpOBKnf+f88rb5w7F8/KsvI3KxHXBmtmEK2M
DGuRFkgW9jsULhj+T06t8hfGOnuzZ/RwV7V70u6PIK+kSWU3mdERRUE3YvydEmhQaQUG6C0dut9FSJpC5MYEJTJkjpQriw/fZLoPz2E/2bar8RdU51uyc47JP2b2fTtNQ4XXh8R8qqAp
8022P5jWyUr47rR3xfo2k2PXS+rw8uPd9VtqyY0lCdUCRkIhMoy5gcWyB/rjp+vP1EevsPzGPKZlS6mDzANGg+OJGcBTa59/soZTSxqBrVtQQK9hd0ao2KYrej50QRT0tp/piGG/tXMi
yzDgsYHQ2Eq+Hb1pZJPIHNZjo4UdvIvIDTxgqpsW/bdphE+ONKT/H1Mfy7qqf3E18U2lMuGHmT/YVGsIhco2ltp6YmLgyL9X3fkD+cX3B11EMKJN06tiW4hvEu9AySDL5SQRENmpvo9a
Ha118jjxb99NenFXKGCJxnH5xutiZl/ibYaBzLDsGVxIPBJkpJy14XdP34or7pYsiC45UlHnTzmbUuD4ANn2OIE0wxMPeTedcqiSWW3Upn0kwZezstDukudqyIcwZRJ79btM7h6cOetW
C9uIIgl26oUNmDzLx/tLZVHzRDE211iVSbn4oDFzqNjC1uPz02Bp2HOsmRuwc3tkACs6UP7yXIPxAmexgqbiYp0iy7KoVxUdnnA6HxD5EL/na+zmwdHDFmmRW6Vey8M83KhQaOVIamSi
9AG7tp21YstbVx3/bP0LonxctyISr1lh2EH4qjlLGTnWQccM7u1GNaQJhStpYFzIKbakChNVgoSKTRE0jRn9B/+6LaJfvugYfQILmInU0y243L70WYRd6VAr2OO9pnVdyvULnLm7iK04
ys5gXm3bcpm+9TT/G8pzVr2955ND8cN++pgQIUIeFnhYAw6w02dG7P4A+NSRalPODYdrwEVPFK5gUE6cG+vRn9zLEa2BT+q35B//aT1ICt1RIrXbx9JVssOS0l8T8TCrwjkcKYi9pdqi
St3hv//FJDqZ9QarG77GSOCHYO5ldYdUijIBTFwHkmG1u9gogbjcOytH1Jy9hmXAvb+3/f5X80hkEey9VHzjMJmcsivRLvU1My3vb1Tlrp/eNb8Z/as41yDy4rQT5hqCuQBVjFO5nEAC
PFbSMKe8W/+uoEijTxhApBolYVZzEvDiYM/0zEQC5REJp0ZQaTiWAadEXIsV2oBFPi9S2ZkrTnW5pmmDE7BKDtssxiNdmrGSeQe/bcAPmYmWxFeQrDOTevtyb6EZmvUcxJL5AaJTcA9g
e8RVyV09TFvStd6eUuKEoHO7BYpSnJXF4evnP2qLSozcZPtOnYxE3D1qxnJcx1xSl0j3OHEWc66sWB/U3P3awbPoMKLjAsTJTJnCqWxYntNMsQdvAcWLVgbEOkDdNnYH50PgQsujZcSd
Q8Vx9Kii+bUQyh+1C/FC4ohuhtKYGP2c1DTqQ0A9NVm8nwsWGUrg+sVA+QehwFhEakYiKy5r9rc9pLR5hixWxDTpZqx98gMJohFrJDWJ9VjZeaiciR+fizEyyMCT3NCFMmeGNka8DSMR
gOWu5/0mEdgqN0zU0OVCsGD0a086PlyNq202eQqhDYEiXYyip0m5AdzCl/8V9r9m7xmTKg0kbypw0FIJkQonwex2TZ2oGL2437+Youcw55HYWT/RJt3ubsOUJYuJOzxNRmNyziBCyXEG
eWKVyqAp1V0koF/8QjpkYpLmcJ0eCFgODDEidtt8Zl/GlJAAWQF/v7wX/ZnsDBgvdK7Swyx+USCX6Xm0yumrhDionYPQZAgat+3VjqV2ZVGC7/rtpuvQkaMIn+4tNuEPfudxkZ2LhNwh
9NGxKex4KIykxBbaPOt5WaW7TqiVmGwQMK7dkqIcG9s2gMdGFGPWzaApb3xwyWOwVp++7aC5ROBumH0JC+UybNNUTGxpKvs9c0Q1+7hZDanS6PkIXt2E3420hx5cDjnUQCWA6BgqMmLj
XR/ACRwOp5uD2mmN5Y52C1rKiMOOugUdeRPqUkCy+EA6aP2gG+UxCTxn10dufpAHuo0FrgJkppHuhEaZyLTnnwxqNtiRW0qux1GuXRbqtDKNXWY1ktKrsHJwbC9DhE+zHHqp87aNDT7H
vyDAD1bDRnOYwqo8fMeLLtqkxKlDkCgTdmUkyO/Ex0jTg9OEeAsh5sQMI8xHvKocRPWEM6lVPLlPjuKsDTnWRNx8469nwWfewsz9FvoeHA6gVIfuBk75dNIsjA3gtIOXUKCFruo9GQCH
d9h9BYQplVsgO5kLKWAaI/zeb7/L1MzwhrLChda5Apj6zSLMPTruPXV8Hkyp4EbvsVF5MfENQDDs2FrNR6PeBLWoAHlpfuwf0MKXsVb3oeNU2ujK+h+RNLCVmQZnPzSDYoVDm7/rl7/g
Fdhr/1DajPPqDs2fPW8v0EW8Em7T6K8LcKMGaufPFVr85kWt52imgnYUJNOGUOJMtqrA+IrbnArGJ8oFfC44vtL1S1X0d1awNBR1oZpZ3WPDBpM4EiIDp7FHtgUaLmlnmzjutIwf/sJk
K8aXHZiI9mOYFuAOZsSm3rKjr3hCUdr5E43yhkIGcp6aJgpOip+nPDmseT5QXbiZpd9NuJcobjqA48wtshYf82c14ThPT9Ej5ETyMRwZDjTgrUFcnTCPdWYnKyQPlx/oDOWAszeag6dw
EcgG0LuT6MfFU+qqchdOqJn807KT/Vqummn0oVRZIhn2hKsy2PJECv2l6vz45th5SR9MhR3l/+DtO5j/y1mdX4lNpibBkzfj+3BYp5HaLbYb6v3QeOpqPjadSS8HPsaklKq+qgMBp+9x
T6hlS2tS537lL1peDrD4IIKZmiQOrNbpTdAJ2uIQuIRQo51ruI+8/I1mbC9zTkpAfHE4QUSSyqoN7vNcqIKtIEDfQdjMu5fZG5PJkdoACE3z2a5VPwMV2sNQNnUpLh8bWYlxd5Sq73ea
n8ioKH9Wh2Kssap3+lb5vVtMzXR/1rGSsRFktw0SWRDjwSCkXi6EZoMrmQ9UCnPSUbkhQo3KYwrEJ5QvjazIpFRhrxO9gR9bo2c35iXAkER7Md3xYi8vstTdAQPQjgQEhl/JQbaoXCsV
Xwe6S/mZ3WJFVYh/O/hpdBoe8mlS9bwh
V/INFO-----------------------------------(  766): -------------------
```

**Last remaining chunk:**

```
V/INFO-----------------------------------(  766): -------------------
V/        (  766): EeQstUMzrB+jgIuFI2w9TgOAdSu9LAyBBJ7BgRuMP/EyzqP2x8pQMTiCaMKZZf7UuKmp18ud/2R/wdQ4MI9CfgTrtDlmiqmQ5MthJh/e8ozf9UZJKZdpVXEQI
6BxUCaJQzHnwWUxuTBo9P1zBGojJ7T6oc1IquYz0R6Z4qPfmL0v7n8OyskDOWzAFXYiGCrc9WvmY6vleyNGCA+Ivf8Xh7G5czUIQjsQBUdcqCWXq1hgCIts5KQHwGG0UDCTZxf4cZxxK
K7N2awkTAeev82lw0ZfSqKUnZWJGdEK9Nip7NEL5eQy3wxvQVvVuChwX0/u4k9DJbaVwLusrt9G4GRNQzOdw179rWUCyLWcV0HPqTWhzdI69Ur8evmaKB9SGcjBevFlx3SZ7kQK2+8UA
B83YL4QXef734tIiUYomQ+k6CYgaWF+cjG/+Vv3r+x0IynVd9QI0nHxJVTZfCtAF6I7xAdlYzra3ej0eYvULOKhMd4mFdhmjKYVpMqpscG9Yo1PW0mSdZRAAHK3TXE9Xwwb4QflFnSzm
yiJ3D4gJe+fduR0sFtuij7i7fhHmU7GAr8QtAS4dkZcVkjnvnURVx5ko1c2lz+HNFT6CjuNoFNhcEyLMmYoEpeY98aR+514PP7NcM79Kn6gdmsYYpXWL6cF60tcKj0cSETRHN/4aEDyR
Chwd9vjxKDUmCGxjhp5yZCa2XWI7AB78a3+7zRvkCnderCEsj5048oGFadLTgBc57MX9XBvSFK9HewmlWC6JNQ1L6bWmeua4bkPhNKec8hbn0wyqvC+oIYFKaWxdmCQ0yfMyo2hgfEe4
e69P9hfcMNtz/xTGraFY/rVt8cq/ObCblWn/0fSrQQhCZjnMAw/4mryk1aSZG6Ga4TKZet082c09ybep+sFBxrrELup5r6Pw6dwqy6k3VlRAEU1K8yX5NQ74nBh8aJ6h49HCwdLedFb/
za5kWmj6WAoJj1zXAfy6kp6CnImPvSlZOx0ZPjEMdCe6fg8IiSiOmlXaVaaIAae
```

Using some text editor and comparing, the original content is the same as the first chunk.

Comment: It is definitely not doing so. Show your log message. Are you sure you didn't change the postData reference? Is it exactly 6144 bytes?

Comment: I strongly suspect you're misreading your diagnostics. Please include the results of your logging. (I'd also *strongly* urge you not to use the default encoding for strings like that. IIRC, the default encoding is UTF-8, which means a character can take multiple bytes. If this is arbitrary binary data, it's even worse, and you *will* lose data...)

Comment: i can assure you i am not misreading the log and i as you can see from above the different log statements produce EXACTLY the same results for both

Comment: You aren't logging postData and have not posted logs. Not sure what info you want people to go on.